# How to create page with post content in it?

Tags: posts, wp-query, pages

I have a page that I would like users to remain on. It is like a reference guide.

Hence I would like to load post content into the page without the header / sidebar etc. Just the post content.

Example:

```
A dog is man's best friend. You can read more about it below.
<Post Title>
<Post Content>
You can also search for more animals here.
```

Do kindly assist.

Comment: You can do it with including wp-config.php and also include the global $wpdb; in your file.

Comment: could you be kind enough to go into details.. i am clueless.. ( not a dev )

Comment: Is that reference guide also a wordpress page? Or external stuff?

Comment: hi . . the reference guide is a wordpress page..  so basically i am trying to show contents of posts in a page ( without showing the header / side bar / footers that usually comes with the post )

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API):

```php
add_shortcode('title', function ($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'id' => null,
    ], $atts);

    $title = '';

    if (!empty($atts['id'])) {
        $title = get_the_title($atts['id']);
    }

    return $title;
});

add_shortcode('content', function ($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'id' => null,
    ], $atts);

    $content = '';

    if (!empty($atts['id'])) {
        $post = get_post($atts['id']);

        // Full content, disregarding "read more" tags:
        $content = str_replace('<!--more-->', '', $post->post_content);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

        // Alternatively, simply use this which respects "read more" tags.
        #$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    }

    return $content;
});
```

Drop this into *functions.php* of the theme you are using.

In your page you can then use `[title id="42"]` and `[content id="42"]`, where `42` is the ID of the post you want to display.

Comment: it works!!!  thanks alot mary..  if i may, this is the ultimate go to that i need : https://essentialsbymor.com/essential-oils-reference-guide/    if you notice, under singles, there are many posts image pulled it by a plugin call   ultimate shortcodes  . . is it possible to click on that image and load the respective post  or even open a new window with only the title and content?

Comment: It surely is possible. But that's out of scope for StackExchange and you should probably hire someone to do that.